# defaultSearchField not working after upgrade to solr3.6

Tags: solr

We have just migrated from solr3.5 to solr3.6, for all this time we have been querying solr as,

```
http:/localhost:8080/solr/<<corename>>/?q=apple
```

But now this is not working and the name of the search field needs to be provided everytime, which was not the case earlier. What might be casing this?

Regards,
Rohit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the default search field has been deprecated in Solr 3.6.
Check [SOLR-2724 - Deprecate defaultSearchField and defaultOperator defined in schema.xml](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2724).

You can add `qf` param with the field to be searched upon in the request handler.

Answer (score 2):

In the solrconfig.xml you can provide Solr default params. I think you should configure them.

You'll find this information in your aolrconfig.xml int he comments. Just configure them and it will work. Also you can configure a default handler by putting default="true" while defining the handler int he solrconfig.xml

In your precise case you will have to add the line within your standard search handler tags

```
<lst name="defaults">  
   <str name="fl">default_fieldname</str>
   <!-- more default params -->
</lst>
```

Comment: I think this should be referring to df rather than fl.